# numInputRows are always 0 in Streaming - Databricks Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, streaming, databricks

I am new to Databricks. The below piece of code is not returning any record. It always returns Zero. 0 rec/s is the result all the time. No details are found in the checkpoint location also.Creating a view on the data frame order_df and executing a select query on this is returning results. Hence there should be a problem with write stream. Please give me suggestions.

```
    order_schema="customerId String, orderId string, products Array<Struct<productId: string, quantity: long, soldPrice: double>>,salesRepId string, shippingAddress Struct<address:string, attention:string, city:string, state:string, zip:string >,submittedAt string "

    from pyspark.sql.functions import *
    order_df=((spark.readStream
      .schema(order_schema)
      .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
       .json(stream_path)         
     ).withColumn("submitted_at",to_timestamp("submittedAt"))
       .withColumn("ingested_at", current_timestamp() )
      .withColumn("ingest_file_name", input_file_name())
       .selectExpr( "submitted_at",
                          "substring(submittedAt,1,7) as submitted_yyyy_mm",
                          "orderId as order_id", 
                          "customerId as customer_id",
                          "salesRepId as sales_rep_id",
                          "shippingAddress.attention as shipping_address_attention",
                          "shippingAddress.address as shipping_address_address",
                          "shippingAddress.city as shipping_address_city", 
                          "shippingAddress.state as shipping_address_state",
                          "cast(shippingAddress.zip as int) as shipping_address_zip",
                          "ingest_file_name",
                          "ingested_at")
     )




    order_df1=order_df.writeStream.format("delta")
    .partitionBy("submitted_yyyy_mm").outputMode("append").trigger(processingTime="1 
     second")
    .queryName(orders_table)
    .option("checkpointLocation",orders_checkpoint_path)
    .start("dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/dbacademy_rmani_deloitte_com_db.db/orders")
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing the files of the  checkpoint location (orders_checkpoint_path) and using table() instead start() resolved the issue.

dbutils.fs.rm(orders_checkpoint_path, True)
order_df1=order_df.writeStream.format("delta")

.partitionBy("submitted_yyyy_mm").outputMode("append").trigger(processingTime="1
second")
.queryName(orders_table)
.option("checkpointLocation",orders_checkpoint_path)
.start(order_table)